# Effectiveness of brass knuckles as a last ditch weapon

Tags: martial-arts, hand-to-hand-combat

Would brass knuckles be capable of harming an individual wearing 14th century plate armor? I.e. could a human realistically impart the amount of force needed to disable or incapacitate an individual with a fist-based weapon?

Comment: Hi, the first part of your question is definitely on topic here.  But asking follow-up questions is liable to get your question closed.  One of the rules is one question at a time.

Comment: Thank you I'll edit it too be better.

Comment: Effective, but only if your armored knight is Tyrion Lannister and your puncher is Gregor Clegane.

Comment: Maybe you can distract him by throwing them into the bushes so he goes to investigate the noise.

Comment: When it comes to plate armor, you want to concentrate a lot of force on a very small place to maximize the strength and potentially dent the armor. These things usually mean you want a long stick with a blunt spike you can swing at the knight like seen in medieval war hammers.

Answer (score 11):

> Would brass knuckles be capable of harming an individual wearing 14th century plate armor?

Maybe if you loaded them into a cannon?

> I.e. could a human realistically impart the amount of force needed to disable or incapacitate an individual with a fist-based weapon?

There's a bit of a gulf between "brass knuckles" and "fist based weapon". The latter, after all, could be some kind of weird metal gauntlet mated with a mace, pick or hammer, and whilst it probably wouldn't be as useful as an conventional weapon, clearly such weapons were capable of disabling or incapacitating armored opponents.

But punching someone in decent armor? If you're lucky they'll put you out of your misery *before* you smash your hand and/or wrist.

No, if you're unarmed at that close in and have use of your hands, you should be using some kind of wrestling. The obvious one that springs to mind is [jujutsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jujutsu):

> Jujutsu developed to combat the samurai of feudal Japan as a method for defeating an armed and armored opponent in which one uses no form of weapon, or only a short weapon. Because striking against an armored opponent proved ineffective, practitioners learned that the most efficient methods for neutralizing an enemy took the form of pins, joint locks, and throws.

I've no doubt that plenty of other societies had related techniques used for similar purposes. Punching your opponent makes for a good sport, but it is a risky and limited technique to use in actual combat. A judiciously timed throw would certainly *look* pretty awesome, and be pretty effective at taking an opponent out of the fight if only for a moment... long enough to run away, or to hit them with a rock or something.

Comment: +1 for the image of firing a load of brass knuckles out of a cannon.  I know wikipedia has "jujitsu" but it should be "jiu jitsu" two words and the i in the first word. Heh, maybe armor boy needs help getting up if you trip him with a nice Royce Gracie move.

Comment: @Dan jiu-jitsu is portuguese romanization, via brazil, vs the more standardized hepburn romanization as jujutsu. I'd usually reach for the BJJ version myself (its the one I've seen most often) but I don't think it can claim to be more correct. I _do_ now want to see a nice MMA-vs-HMA video analyzing suitable wrestling moves to use on people in full plate, though...

Answer (score 6):

That sounds like a good way to break your knuckles. Not the brass ones, though they might bend if you hit someone hard enough, your own ones.

Knuckledusters are a force multiplier, but they're pretty much at the bottom of the pile for such things. If you use them in anger it hurts you as well as the target. If you use them against a target wearing a harder metal as armour, there's only one person getting injured and it isn't them.

You might as well be using Timmy's mallet for all the good it'll do.

Comment: I figured as much, I had a really cool scene planned but I don't want the rule of cool to overcome the rule of realism. I'm assuming it would be the same results if the knuckles were made out of steel?

Comment: @Inserttext, if they were steel you might manage to put a surface dent in the armour, depending where you hit and how well made the armour is and how well made your knuckledusters are.

Comment: Re, "...break your knuckles..." Proper brass knuckles _don't_ exert any force on your own knuckles. The force for the blow comes [from the palm of your hand](https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/brass-knuckle-duster-weapon-for-hand-isolated-on-white-backgro-gm514630612-88195313).

Answer (score 2):

With a blunt one? Maybe repeated hits to the helmet might shake their head enough to knock them unconscious, eventually. In that case, the most critical part of the brass knuckles would probably be the cushioning used to protect the attacker's hand. If the attacker hits the helmet at a bad angle, a single strike could break bones in their hand. Maybe a plate armor glove would be better, but I have little knowledge of the ergonomics of these gloves.

If the fist weapon features a spike, that could be used to target small gaps in the plate armor. Whether or not such a fist-knife is efficient enough to warrant carrying one instead of just a normal knife, I don't know.

Without a pointy spike, my intuition suggest a heavy stone would probably work better then brass knuckles. Especially when swung in a wide arc to gain momentum.

Answer (score 1):

"Harming"? probably not significantly

"Incapacitating"? definitely ... but probably not in the way you'd expect.

I've noticed most of the answers seem rather defeatist (not that they don't have good reasons, but I feel they overlook important things), so I'm going to try and highlight the potential benefits, instead.

As others have mentioned, brass is software than the steel used in most plate armor, but thickness can overcome that to some extent.  It's also been pointed out that under the armor would be padding.  Finally, it's been mentioned that different areas of armor are thicker than others.

Something not mentioned, which is especially noteworthy with your inclusion of the word 'incapacitate' in your question, is that plate armor has a significant weakness *other than* the gaps that were mentioned.  And that weakness is the key to making brass knuckles effective against plate armor.

But before we get in to that weakness, lets take a look at actual weapons that were specialized for defeating armor:

Lance - this used the power of a horse, concentrated to a tiny point, to brute force its way through even very tough, thick, high quality armor.  This tactic is certainly not going to work for brass knuckles

Polearms - these used extra reach, swung in a wide arc, to amplify the speed with which the damage dealing bit of the weapon contacted the target. They also used the weight of the metal damage dealing bit at the end to increase momentum.  Together this extra speed and mass could transfer more energy in to, and sometimes through, the armor.  Again, not going to work much with brass knuckles, though there is a small pit of added mass, but it's negligible compared to the armor.

Spiked maces and war-picks - these used mass, plus a little bit of extra length for speed, to generate more momentum, and then focused it in to pointy bits to try and poke holes in the armor.  It should be noted that these types of weapons rarely got through the padding underneath to actually break the skin, and even when they did, the puncture wounds were generally quite mild.  Their true strength was not in actually reaching the fleshy bits underneath, but in transferring blunt impact force (despite their pointy bits) past the armor (if their helmet rattles their skull back and forth fast enough, their brain also rattles against the inside of their skull, and they lose consciousness even if nothing but padding actually contacted their head), as well as deforming the armor in uncomfortable and inconvenient ways for the armored. Now we're getting closer to how brass knuckles could be useful.

Blunt maces and warhammers - these also used mass, plus a little bit of extra length for speed, to generate more momentum, but instead of focusing that momentum to a fine point, they instead just wanted to make enough contact and grip to avoid glancing off the armor so that they could transfer the maximum amount of that kinetic energy in to the target.  This had the effect of making the armor itself in to the weapon of impact to the person wearing it.  The armor received the momentum, and pushed in to the person underneath it.  It also often deformed armor in uncomfortable and inconvenient ways for the wearer.  And this is the type of thing that brass knuckles would be used for.

Brass knuckles don't provide any extra speed like the staff portions of maces, warhammers, and polearms, but they do provide a but of extra mass.  But the key is that they also protect the hand, so that the attacker can put much more force in to a punch, without increasing risk of injury, than they otherwise would be able to.  So the extra force would come from the attacker's ability to, confidently, put their whole strength and weight behind their strike.  The brass knuckles also work to concentrate that force to a somewhat smaller area.

Now, would they puncture any half decent plate armor on head or chest?  Not a chance. Probably not even dent it...

...BUT...(and this is where that other weakness of plate armor comes in to play)

It could certainly dent the thinner plates, especially arms, and importantly, the joints in the arms.  Joints are the other weakness I mentioned.  Articulated armor joints are actually much more precisely made than most people realize.  A decent dent on or near a joint in the armor can cause the joint to be very stiff, lose range of motion, or possibly even lock up completely.  A serious dent near the elbow could make the wearer lose mobility to the point that it might seem like they were in a cast from shoulder to wrist.  Obviously this could seriously hamper their fighting ability.

Now, there's a reason others mentioned grappling and jiu jitsu, because that's what people generally did when they had less armor than their opponent (or no armor at all), they'd tackle the armored fighter, and hold them down, until they could get a pointy weapon, usually a dagger, through a gap in the armor.

So, for your scenario, I would have to assume that your brass knuckle wielder is both lacking a suitable dagger or dagger-like implement for that tactic, as well as lacking grappling ability in general to get them on the ground and make a hasty retreat, as well as lacking the ability to make a hasty retreat without knocking down the armor wearer.

In this situation, with brass knuckles on hand (pun-intended) and no other reasonable options, they could, with powerful, quick, and accurate strikes, work to disable the joints in the opponents armor.  Elbow would be the best target to cause the most serious immobility without risking getting to far in to grappling range.  An immobilized shoulder would be even better, but the armor near the shoulder will be thicker (so harder to damage/dent), as well as dangerous range as far as grappling is concerned.  Wrists, hands, etc., would be the safest as far as staying out of grappling range, but less likely to be articulated in ways that cause useful immobilization, though punching fist to fist could potentially dislocate fingers even through the armor, depending on the specific type of gauntlet used.  Knees would also be a very good target, as immobilizing a knee joint would probably effectively end the fight, and the armor is not likely to be particularly thick there, but it's in an awkward location to try and hit with hands from a standing position.  But a feint as though you were going to try a grappling maneuver, changed to a strike, might be an effective tactic.

Comment: Thank you for this advice. That was essentially the exact scenario I'm imagining the character being in, he just needs to slow down or temporarily incapacitate the knight to buy some time in order to retrieve a more effective weapon, in which too dispatch the knight with. The knight in this situation has also lost his main weapon and is using a dagger, so the range is still in favor of the knight but not by a huge amount.

Comment: This seems to imply plate armor joints are somewhat fragile. Maybe my understanding of the term is flawed, but I think of something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_armour#/media/File:Savoyard_armour_IMG_3805.jpg). I struggle to see how to dent that with brass knuckles.

Comment: @ooak  First, that particular set of armor is about 200-300 years more advanced than the time period mentioned in the question.  "14th century" is 1300-1400, the image you gave is for 1600.  I'm sorry if it seemed I implied that joints are "fragile", that was not my intention.  Like thrusting a dagger through gaps is not an easy feat, damaging armor joints would not be either.  But "not easy" doesn't mean "impossible".  While denting the armor, at any point, would be difficult, putting a dent in the thinner Vambrace is much easiER (not 'easy') than causing damage through the breastplate

Comment: @Inserttext Something else to consider, 14th century "plate" armor was rarely the "full coverage" armor many people think of when "knight" is mentioned. There were often significant openings in the plates at joints. These gaps were usually protected by mail Voiders. Mail is great against cuts and slashes, but not blunt impact. It almost always had padding under it, but too thick padding at a joint would hamper mobility, so the padding would be slightly less at joints, making a strike to a mail joint, instead of plate, a good option.  see https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zGl_UXc9HIE/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: The kind of plate armor that had precisely fitted joints was made from spring steel, it could deform and return to its original shape under the impact of much better force multiplying weapons the brass knuckles. Armor made before spring steel was an option was not made to such tightly fitted standards that deforming would lock it up.  Instead joints would be filled in with mail or be left completely unarmored.

Comment: @Nosajimiki The time period of the question rules out any significant quantities of anything close to what we would consider modern "spring steel".  For the time period in question, at the very best, only a rare handful of harness would have more than just a steel-like outer surface from carbon penetration and work-hardening.  For the most part, harness in that period would be somewhere between what we currently call 'steel' and what we currently call 'wrought iron' (and leaning more toward the 'wrought iron' side of that spectrum).

Comment: @Harthag You begin seeing spring steels in Europe in the 12th century. By the 14th century, many plate armors would have been spring steel despite lowish carbon content (spring steel can be made from anything in the 0.3–1.7% carbon range). Although full enclosure couters and poleyns were not invented yet; you still saw a lot of tightly fitted moving parts in the form of helmet visors and segmented sabatons and spaulders.  These joints could be seized by an especially powerful weapon like a lance strike, but brass knuckles would not come close to causing a permanent deformation.

Comment: Also, carbon steel does not work harden, it work softens.  A late medieval smith would start off with the highest hardness iron he can forge without cracking, and hammer out the hardening elements until it becomes soft enough to suit his need. In many cases medieval armor had less carbon than modern steels to offset the hardness they also got from phosphorous contamination which we now fully remove because it brittles the steel slightly more than carbon does.

Comment: So a 0.6% carbon, 0.3% phosphorous steel is very similar to a 0.9% pure carbon steel as long as it does not also include significant sulfur contamination.  This makes many medieval steels sound softer than they really were.

Answer (score 1):

Talking about medieval plate armor, your best bet is trying to remove their helmet or open their visor first and then punch the exposed head. Expect to die trying to get close enough to do that though.

Answer (score 0):

## If you punch the arms or legs and the quality is low.

Proper armor often had what is called "Proofing" where you fire a crossbow at each piece to check it's strong. There would be characteristic dents on each piece. Kinda crappy armor was often less well made.

The chest tends to have the thickest armor, followed by the helmet. Arms tended to have thinner and lighter armor. A good blow to the arms might well work to break their arm.

Remember that in addition to armor they would normally wear some leather under it to cushion blows, so heavy weapons were even less effective.

In addition, the armor crumpling is protective to the owner. If the armor is breaking, their bones aren't. You might need repeated blow to the same place (damaging your hand even more, even past the knuckles) to disrupt the armor and leather enough.